# Finding coefficients of a double Fourier series

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

This is the end of a PDE (heat equation in 2D) I am trying to solve with bounds from $0 < x < L$ and $0 < y < H$. It is a Newmann condition problem (i.e. all derivatives of $x$ and $y$ at the end points are $0$). Actually I am not sure if that is a Newmann condition so that would be my first question. Here is my end solution

$$u(x,y,t) = \sum _{ m=0 }^{ \infty  }{ \sum _{ n=0 }^{ \infty  }{ A_{ m,n }\cos  \left( \frac { m\pi x }{ L }  \right)  } \cos \left( \frac { n\pi y }{ H }  \right) e^{\lambda k t}  } $$ with the initial condition $u(x,y,0) = F(x,y)$ for some known function $F(x,y)$ and $\lambda > 0 $ (I don't think the expotential term matters). My second question is: can I split up the coefficients and bring out the constant term, i.e. write the solution like this 
$$u(x,y,t) = A_0 + \sum _{ m=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ A_{ m,n }\cos  \left( \frac { m\pi x }{ L }  \right)  } \cos\left( \frac { n\pi y }{ H }  \right)  e^{\lambda k t}  }.  $$
You can then invoke the initial condition  and are left with 
$$u(x,y,0) =F(x,y) = A_0 + \sum _{ m=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ A_{ m,n }\cos  \left( \frac { m\pi x }{ L }  \right)  } \cos\left( \frac { n\pi y }{ H }  \right)  }. $$
**Then how would I go about finding $A_0$ and $A_{m,n}$?**

I know how to do this for a sin series. Here I can show you my steps: 
\begin{align} 
F(x,y)&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty{\sin{(m\pi x)}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\sin{(n\pi y)}} A_{m,n}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty{\left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty{ A_{m,n} \sin{(n\pi y)}} \right)}\sin{(m\pi x)}\\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty{B_m}\sin{(m\pi x)} 
\end{align}
and so $B_m = \frac{2}{L}\int_0^L F(x,y) \sin{(m\pi x)} dx$ and so you plug this back in and then you get a second integral (a double integral infact in terms of $x$ and $y$) of the coefficient $A_{m,n}$.

---

Edit: The answer I got for $A_{m,n} $ is as follows. Is this correct? 
$$ A_{m,n} = \frac{4}{HL}\int_0^H \int_0^L F(x,y) \cos{\left(\frac{m\pi x}{L}\right)} \cos{\left(\frac{n \pi y}{H}\right)}\, dx dy$$

Comment: I believe you do have Neumann conditions. You definitely can split the term $m = 0$ and $n = 0$ from the sum, but then you still need to keep terms corresponding to $m = 0$ and $n \ne 0$, and also terms corresponding to $m \ne 0$ and $n = 0$. Your sum should be

$$
u(x, y, t) = A_{0,0} + \sum_{m=1}^\infty A_{m,0}\cos\left(\frac{m\pi x}L\right) e^{\lambda_{m,0}t} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty A_{0,n}\cos\left(\frac{n\pi y}H\right)e^{\lambda_{0,n}t} + \sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos\left(\frac{m\pi x}L\right)\cos\left(\frac{n\pi y}H\right)e^{-\lambda_{m,n}t}$$

I can't really recommend doing this.

Comment: BTW, Fourier coefficients for $\cos$ are similar to $\sin$. The only special term is the constant term. I'm not sure what you're confused about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$F(x,y) = A_0 + \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{ A_{m,n}\cos  \left( \frac { m\pi x }{ L }  \right)  } \cos\left( \frac { n\pi y }{ H }  \right)  }$$

Multiply both sides through by $\cos(m'\pi x/L)\cos(n'\pi x/L)$ for arbitrary but fixed positive integers $m'$, $n'$ and integrate over $0<x<L$ and $0<y<H$. The orthogonality if these cosine functions on these intervals will cause all the terms in the series to vanish except when $m=m'$ and $n=n'$, resulting in
$$
\small
\int_0^H\int_0^L F(x,y)\cos(m'\pi x/L)\cos(n'\pi y/H)\,dx\,dy=A_{n'm'}\int_0^H\int_0^L \cos^2(m'\pi x/L)\cos^2(n'\pi y/H)\,dx\,dy
$$
which implies
$$
A_{n'm'}=\frac{\int_0^H\int_0^L F(x,y)\cos(m'\pi x/L)\cos(n'\pi y/H)\,dx\,dy}{\int_0^H\int_0^L \cos^2(m'\pi x/L)\cos^2(n'\pi y/H)\,dx\,dy}.
$$
Since $n'$ and $m'$ were arbitrary dummy indices, we can change them to $n$ and $m$. Also, the integral in the denominator equals ${LH\over 4}$, so we get
$$
A_{nm}={4\over LH}\int_0^H\int_0^L F(x,y)\cos(m\pi x/L)\cos(n\pi y/H)\,dx\,dy.
$$

Answer (score 0):

To calculate $A_{00}$ we just integrate both sides. Note that there are two set of orthogonal functions. ${1, cos({\pi}x/L), cos(2{\pi}x/L), ..., cos(m{\pi}x/L), ...}$ for all m =1, 2, 3...

Similarly the orthogonal set related to n is  ${1, cos({\pi}x/H), cos(2{\pi}x/H), ..., cos(n{\pi}x/H), ...}$ for all n = 1, 2, 3...

We know that
$$ f(x, y) = A_{00} + \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}A_{m0}cos(m{\pi}x/L) +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{0n}cos(n{\pi}y/H) + \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{mn}cos(n{\pi}x/L)cos(n{\pi}y/H) $$

If we integrate both side with respect to x and y from 0 to L and 0 to H respectively we will get

$$
A_{00}=\frac{\int_0^H\int_0^L f(x,y)\,dx\,dy}{\int_0^H\int_0^L dx\,dy} = \frac{\int_0^H\int_0^L f(x,y)\,dx\,dy}{HL}.
$$

This is because $cos(m{\pi}x/L)$ and $cos(n{\pi}y/H)$ are both orthogonal to 1, so all the other terms will equal zero once integration is performed.

In a similar manner we can calculate $A_{m0}$ and $A_{0n}$ and $A_{mn}$.

Comment: This answer does not look any different from the accepted nine year old answer.